# how to push sth to a function returning an array?(is it possible to push to a function returning an array)

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, object

I have a function return an array of objects, I want to push sth to the array but not diractly, atually i want push that to the function, is it possible?

```
hierar() {
        return [{ h: 1 }, { h: 2, hh: [{ u: 2.1 }, { u: 2.2 }] }, { h: 3, hh: [{ u: 4 }, { U: 5 }, { u: 6 }] }, { h: 7 }];
    }

this.hierar().Push({h: 9, hh: [{h:9.1}, {h:9.2}] });
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
hierar(arg) {
    return [{ h: 1 }, { h: 2, hh: [{ u: 2.1 }, { u: 2.2 }] }, { h: 3, hh: [{ u: 4 }, { U: 5 }, { u: 6 }] }, { h: 7 }, ...arg];
}

this.hierar({h: 9, hh: [{h:9.1}, {h:9.2}] });
```

Comment: Yes, Sort of, there is no argument, overall i was tryin to take elements of a very big menu from database to show it in tree(of course tree of wijmo with angular or tree of angular material that need an array of objects of arrays.. ), :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your intention. Have you ever gotten the data once?

Comment: me no, but someone else did it before and made the menu with mat accordion of angular material and did it very messy but i want transform it to tree, for me taking data of database is with some trouble that i could not do it until now,

Answer (score 1):

You could concat the array. [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) returns a new array.

```
array.concat(otherArray)
```

With your code:

```
this.hierar().concat({ h: 9, hh: [{ h: 9.1 }, { h: 9.2 }] });
```